# Jquery : How to make one list not sortable in a set of lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a `<div>` that is sortable. In that `<div>`there are several `<ul>` lists that are sortable with jQuery. How can I make the 'First list' static so it can't be sorted ?

HTML :

```
<div class="overview" id="sortable">
    <div class="viewport-vertical">
      <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="folders-unsortable">
          <li class="unsortable"><h3>First list (3)</h3></li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <a href="" target="_parent" title="verre si li the fox jumps" class="favorite">verre si li the fox jumps</a>
              <a href="#" title="edit" class="icon icon-wheel edit-item"></a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="viewport-vertical">
      <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="folders-sortable">
          <li class="unsortable"><h3>Second list</h3></li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <a href="" target="_parent" title="Lorem ipsum dolor" class="favorite">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
              <a href="#" title="edit" class="icon icon-wheel edit-item"></a>
            </div>
          </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      //Folders
      $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
      $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

      //Make favorites sortable
      $( ".folders-sortable" ).sortable({
        items: "ul:not(.unsortable)",
        connectWith: ".folders-sortable",
        update: function( event, ui ) {
        if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
              alert("Favorite moved");
          }
      }
      }).disableSelection();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 $(function()
{
     $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
     $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( "#sortable .folders-sortable" ).sortable();
});
```